# Generate the outcome of the flip of a fair coin (A question from A First Course In Probability by Ross)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The book asks the question:

> Suppose that we want to generate the outcome
>   of the flip of a fair coin, but that all we have at
>   our disposal is a biased coin which lands on heads
>   with some unknown probability p that need not be
>   equal to 0.5. Could we use the procedure that continues
>   to flip the coin until the last two flips are
>   different and then lets the result be the outcome
>   of the final flip to generate the outcome of the flip of a fair coin ?

An analysis made showed that the probability of answering H is $p(1-p)$ [this is since the only case that answers H is the case that the curent flip is H and the previews flip is T]. the same argument shows that the probability of answering T is also $p(1-p)$.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why, even if $p=0.5$ we get the conclusion that the probability of answering H is not 0.5 ? [I know $p(1-p) \not=0.5 $ for any real p, but what is the reason intuitivly ? My intuition  sais that by symmetry the answer is 0.5]
2. How is it possible that we got $P(H)+P(T)\not=1$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculations of the probabilities of getting a string of tails followed by a head and a string of heads followed by a tail are incorrect. The probability of getting $k$ heads followed by a tail is $p^k(1-p)$, so the probability of getting a string of heads followed by a tail is

$$\sum_{k\ge 1}p^k(1-p)=(1-p)\frac{p}{1-p}=p\;.$$

Similarly, the probability of getting a string of tails followed by a head is

$$\sum_{k\ge 1}p(1-p)^k=p\sum_{k\ge 1}(1-p)^k=p\frac{1-p}p=1-p\;.$$

Comment: Are you sure you understood the procedure ? It does not say to answer H after a string of tails followed by a head but rather after getting a string with the 2 last flips different and the last flip is the answer...

Comment: @Belgi: You flip the coin until the last two flips are different. If this takes $n$ flips, the first $n-1$ flips must have been the same, and the $n$-th flip must have been different from the first $n-1$. If the $n$-th flip is $H$, for instance, you must have had $n-1$ $T$’s followed by $H$. Thus, the only way the procedure can answer $H$ is to be of the form $T^kH$ for some $k\ge 1$.

Comment: I think that you are correct, but I do think that thq question (if to make it more formal) ment: 1.Flip the coin, 2.Flip it again, if both flips were the same return to 1 otherwise the answer is the result of the last flip. giving that this is the procedure I'm guessing that I am still wrong but I don't know why...thank you for your time and help!

Comment: But the question in the book says to show that getting heads or tails is equally likely

Comment: @Guacho: No, it does not: it asks *whether* these outcomes are equally likely. They are not.